# docker compose, swarm and ip address inside dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I will make this simple as i can and i will start for example. Imagine that we have to configure postgresql replication and some web app that will be used it. docker-compose.yml may look like this

```
web:
  build: ./webapp/web
  ports:
    - "7000:7000"
  links:
    - pgpool2

pgpool2:
  build: ./pgpool2
  ports:
    - "9999:9999"
  links:
    - master
    - slave

master:
  build: ./master
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"

slave:
  build: ./slave
  links:
    - master
```

inside dockerfiles(master, slave) we need to put ip addresses to each other for example(master)

FROM ubuntu

```
....
RUN echo "host replication repuser 172.17.0.3/0  md5"  >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "host all         all     172.17.0.2/0 md5"   >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "host all         all     172.17.0.2/0 trust"   >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "host all         pgpool  172.17.0.4/0 trust" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "host all         all     172.17.0.4/0 md5"   >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
.....
```

This solution is ugly but even if i put some variables instead of typing ip addresses by myself there is a problem. docker swarm puts containers for all available hosts(ip addresses for each container are changing). the only solution to may it work is to put some variable that has valid ip address. for example if we have this line

```
RUN echo "host all         all     172.17.0.2/0 md5"   >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
```

i need some variable named the same like service so in this example master and this value need to has valid ip address. otherwise there is no possibility that this will work because ip address of each service will be changing dynamically by swarm(containers are placed randomly by swarm). If i am wrong please correct me.

Comment: Which version of Docker are you using? Version 1.9 introduces Docker Networking. You nog longer need to use links. Docker version 1.10 contains a new docker-compose file which makes it really easy for containers to find each other with service discovery.

Comment: Thanks for answer but this is not really what i want. I have to put ip address inside dockerfile. It's impossible to configure for example postgresql stream replication without putting some ip addresses inside pg_hba. Its not a problem to connect master and slave container that they can see each other. Problem starting when you have to put in configuration file ip address to master or slave. In other words definition of configuration files should be dynamic. I like docker but i think that something like this just can't be done.